# How do I get total sum of data in every 3 minutes against 2 different IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have a DataFrame like this:

```
ID-A   ID-B   time 
A      1      2022-02-14 00:01:07
              2022-02-14 00:02:06
              2022-02-14 00:02:55

A      2      2022-02-14 00:00:07
              2022-02-14 00:01:07
```

I want to sum it in a way such that each combination of `ID1` and `ID2` I have total sum of instances in every 3 minutes.
The issue with calling resample for every 3 minutes is that it creates a new dataframe where the IDs are not retained.

Desired dataframe:

```
A     1    3
A     2    2
```

Comment: [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html?highlight=groupby%20count#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count) should get you there

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID-A':['A','A','A','A','A'],'ID-B':[1,1,1,2,2],
'time':['02-14-2022 00:01:07','02-14-2022 00:02:06','02-14-2022 00:02:55','02-14-2022 00:00:07','02-14-2022 00:01:07']})

df['datetime'] =pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.sort_values(['ID-A','ID-B','datetime'],inplace=True)

df_final = df.groupby(['ID-A','ID-B']).count().reset_index()
df_final

# df.dtypes
```

Hi Brother, if you only need the counts based on the group, please use the code above, but if you need the 3 mins as a group please confirm for me, I need to adjust the code

Thanks
Leon

You want to get output like.

```
A     1    3
A     2    2
```

If A and 1 has 4 records but 3 of them in 3 min but the last one is not, the output will be like this right?

```
A     1    3
A     1    1
A     2    2
```